# Angular Performance Functions in Template vs properties. How Do I measure the performance? Is One way Faster?

Tags: angular, angular-forms

**I need to show a message when an input is touched and invalid. There are several input where I needed to do this so I created a function: Let me re-iterate this form has SEVERAL controls on it,so I need consider re-use if possible**

```
isInvalid = (control: AbstractControl): boolean => {
    const invalid = (control.touched && control.invalid);
    return invalid;
  }
```

In the HTML template I do this:

```
<input autocomplete="off" id="firstName" class="form-control" formControlName="firstName">
          <div *ngIf="isInvalid(firstName)"> Please enter a valid value </div>
```

Now of course this called the invalid function numerous times. so I tried this approach and removed the function and just called the properties on the form control.

```
<input autocomplete="off" id="lastName" class="form-control" formControlName="lastName">          
          <div *ngIf="lastName.touched && lastName.invalid"> Please enter a valid value </div>
```

**I can't find any way to prove that this way is better for performance. 
Then I got the bright idea to extend the form control and do something like this:**

```
export class FormControlExtended extends FormControl {

    touchedAndInvalid = false;
    constructor(formState?: any,
        validatorOrOpts?: ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[] | AbstractControlOptions | null,
        asyncValidator?: AsyncValidatorFn | AsyncValidatorFn[] | null) {
        super(formState, validatorOrOpts, asyncValidator);

        this.statusChanges
            .subscribe(() => {
                this.markTouchAndInvalid();
            });
    }


    markAsTouched({ onlySelf }: { onlySelf?: boolean } = {}): void {
        super.markAsTouched({ onlySelf });
        this.markTouchAndInvalid();
    }

    markTouchAndInvalid = () => {
        this.touchedAndInvalid = (this.touched && this.invalid);
    }
}
```

and in the html I do this

```
<input autocomplete="off" id="lastName" class="form-control" formControlName="lastName">          
          <div *ngIf="lastName.touchedAndInvalid"> Please enter a valid value </div>
```

**My Questions:**
Is one way better than the other? How could I prove it with some tool or extension that one way has better performance? Is there a better way? Am I off my rocker?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about performance measure's but the convention I use is a [getter/setter](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/typescript-setters-getter).

```js
this.exampleForm = this.fb.group({
  lastName: ''
});

get isValid() {
  const ctrl = this.exampleForm.get('exampleControl');
  return ctrl.touched && ctrl.invalid;
}
```

```html
<input autocomplete="off" id="lastName" class="form-control" formControlName="lastName">
<div *ngIf="isValid"> Please enter a valid value </div>
```

Comment: The issue I have with this is, I will need an isValid getter for every control on the form. I have several inputs on my form. If I could prove this way is faster then I could add it to the control I extended from FormControl. If you add a console.log('isValid called') in your getter function you MIGHT see that it is called several time. I thank you for providing an answer.